# $L^q([\mathbb{R}])\nsubseteq L^p([\mathbb{R}])$ and $L^p([\mathbb{R}])\nsubseteq L^q([\mathbb{R}])$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $1\leq p<q\leq \infty$ I have to how that

$L^q([\mathbb{R}])\nsubseteq L^p([\mathbb{R}])$ and $L^p([\mathbb{R}])\nsubseteq L^q([\mathbb{R}]) $

I was trying to come up with counterexamples for the inclusion but unfortunately, I am stuck! I would appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $k \in (\dfrac{1}{q}, \dfrac{1}{p})$
and we can define 2 functions $$f_{p} = \dfrac{\chi_{(0,1]}(x)}{x^{-k}}$$
$$f_q = \dfrac{\theta(x-1)}{x^{-k}}$$
Where $\chi(x)$ - is a charachteristic function and $\theta(x-1)$ is heaviside function. It's easy to see, that $f_{q} \in L_{q}(\mathbb R), f_{q} \notin L_{p}(\mathbb R)$ and $f_{p} \in L_{p}(\mathbb R), f_{p} \notin L_{p}(\mathbb R)$

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the function $f(x)= x^{-2p/(p+q)}, x \in (0,1]$ where $1<p<q<\infty $ then you can show that $f \in L^p $ but $f \not\in L^q.$
There is a nuiance here though that you are looking at Lebesgue integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ but we only did it for the interval $(0,1]$. You can restrict your functions to $[\epsilon, 1]$ for small $\epsilon >0 $ and set the function to zero everywhere else. You can then apply the monotone convergence theorem and show the limit function is $L^p (\mathbb{R}) $ but not $L^q(\mathbb{R})$.
To show the opposite inclusion doesn't hold, do the same but using the functions restricted to $[1,n]$ instead and zero everywhere else.

Comment: But in the first case with $f(x)=x^{-2/(p+q}$ don´t we need a sequence of functions?

Comment: And how ever I try, it seems I can´t prove that $f(x)\in L^p$ and not in $f(x) \nin L^q$

Comment: You can take the sequence as $f_n(x) =x^{-2/p+q)}\chi _{[1/n, 1]} $. The point of all this being that $ \int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha} \ dx $ converges if and only if $\alpha >-1$ and in our case $-2p/(p+q)>-1 $ whilst $-2q/(p+q)<-1 $.